Detect State using js Display Data from Arry and Show in Fields Issue
I have and js Script that i have write it the scrip is use from State Prediction of State .
How its Working for Example if the number Comes from Dialers and Display IN HTML number is 415-5299*** it  will show its from CA
// Array of USA state names
const states = [
    'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia',
    'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland',
    'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey',
    'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina',
    'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];

// Function to get current time for a state
function getCurrentTime(state) {
    const currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { timeZone: `America/${state}` });
    return `${state}: ${currentTime}`;
}

// Display current time for all USA states in a div element
const displayDiv = document.getElementById('display');
states.forEach(state => {
    const currentTime = getCurrentTime(state);
    const stateTimeElement = document.createElement('p');
    stateTimeElement.textContent = currentTime;
    displayDiv.appendChild(stateTimeElement);
});

// Function to get current time zone for a state
function getCurrentTimeZone(state) {
    const timeZone = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { timeZoneName: 'short', timeZone: `America/${state}` }).split(' ')[2];
    return timeZone;
}

// Display current time and time zone for all USA states in a div element
states.forEach(state => {
    const currentTime = getCurrentTime(state);
    const timeZone = getCurrentTimeZone(state);
    const stateTimeElement = document.createElement('p');
    stateTimeElement.textContent = `${currentTime} (${timeZone})`;
    displayDiv.appendChild(stateTimeElement);
});
// Function to get current time for Pakistan
function getCurrentTimePakistan() {
    const currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Karachi' });
    return `Pakistan: ${currentTime}`;
}

// Display current time for Pakistan in a div element
const pakistanTimeElement = document.createElement('p');
pakistanTimeElement.textContent = getCurrentTimePakistan();
displayDiv.appendChild(pakistanTimeElement);

// Function to detect number of states and cities
function detectNumberOfStatesAndCities() {
    const numberOfStates = states.length;
    let numberOfCities = 0;

    states.forEach(state => {
        numberOfCities += getCitiesByState(state).length;
    });

    return `Number of states: ${numberOfStates}, Number of cities: ${numberOfCities}`;
}

// Function to get cities by state
function getCitiesByState(stateCode) {
    switch (stateCode) {
        case 'AL':
            return ['205', '251', '256', '334'];
        case 'AK':
            return ['907'];
        case 'AZ':
            return ['480', '520', '602', '623', '928'];
        case 'AR':
            return ['479', '501', '870'];
        case 'CA':
            return ['209', '213', '310', '323', '408', '415', '424', '510', '530', '559', '562', '619', '626', '650', '661', '707', '714', '760', '805', '818', '831', '858', '909', '916', '925', '949', '951'];
        case 'CO':
            return ['303', '719', '720', '970'];
        case 'CT':
            return ['203', '860'];
        case 'DE':
            return ['302'];
        case 'DC':
            return ['202'];
        case 'FL':
            return ['689', '239', '305', '321', '352', '386', '407', '561', '727', '754', '772', '786', '813', '850', '863', '904', '941', '954'];
        case 'GA':
            return ['762', '229', '404', '478', '678', '706', '770', '912'];
        case 'HI':
            return ['808'];
        case 'ID':
            return ['208'];
        case 'IL':
            return ['730', '779', '217', '224', '309', '312', '447', '618', '630', '708', '773', '815', '847'];
        case 'IN':
            return ['219', '260', '317', '574', '765', '812'];
        case 'IA':
            return ['319', '515', '563', '641', '712'];
        case 'KS':
            return ['316', '620', '785', '913'];
        case 'KY':
            return ['270', '502', '606', '859'];
        case 'LA':
            return ['225', '318', '337', '504', '985'];
        case 'ME':
            return ['207'];
        case 'MD':
            return ['240', '301', '410', '443'];
        case 'MA':
            return ['339', '351', '413', '508', '617', '774', '781', '857', '978'];
        case 'MI':
            return ['231', '248', '269', '313', '517', '586', '616', '734', '810', '906', '947', '989'];
        case 'MN':
            return ['218', '320', '507', '612', '651', '763', '952'];
        case 'MS':
            return ['228', '601', '662'];
        case 'MO':
            return ['769', '314', '417', '573', '636', '660', '816'];
        case 'MT':
            return ['406'];
        case 'NE':
            return ['308', '402'];
        case 'NV':
            return ['702', '775'];
        case 'NH':
            return ['603'];
        case 'NJ':
            return ['201', '551', '609', '732', '848', '856', '862', '908', '973'];
        case 'NM':
            return ['505', '575'];
        case 'NY':
            return ['212', '315', '347', '516', '518', '585', '607', '631', '646', '716', '718', '845', '914', '917'];
        case 'NC':
            return ['252', '336', '704', '828', '910', '919', '980'];
        case 'ND':
            return ['701'];
        case 'OH':
            return ['216', '234', '330', '419', '440', '513', '567', '614', '740', '937'];
        case 'OK':
            return ['405', '580', '918'];
        case 'OR':
            return ['503', '541', '971'];
        case 'PA':
            return ['215', '267', '412', '484', '570', '610', '717', '724', '814', '878'];
        case 'RI':
            return ['401'];
        case 'SC':
            return ['803', '843', '864'];
        case 'SD':
            return ['605'];
        case 'TN':
            return ['423', '615', '731', '865', '901', '931'];
        case 'TX':
            return ['210', '214', '254', '281', '325', '361', '409', '430', '432', '469', '512', '682', '713', '806', '817', '830', '832', '903', '915', '936', '940', '956', '972', '979'];
        case 'UT':
            return ['435', '801'];
        case 'VT':
            return ['802'];
        case 'VA':
            return ['276', '434', '540', '571', '703', '757', '804'];
        case 'WA':
            return ['206', '253', '360', '425', '509'];
        case 'WV':
            return ['681', '304'];
        case 'WI':
            return ['262', '414', '608', '715', '920'];
        case 'WY':
            return ['307'];
        case 'AS':
            return ['684'];
        case 'GU':
            return ['671'];
        case 'MP':
            return ['670'];
        case 'PR':
            return ['787', '939'];
        case 'UM':
            return ['808'];
        case 'VI':
            return ['340'];
        default:
            return [];
    }
}

// Function to display state names
function displayStateNames() {
    const stateInput = document.querySelector('.state-us');
    const stateSelect = document.createElement('select');
    states.forEach(state => {
        const stateOption = document.createElement('option');
        stateOption.value = state;
        stateOption.textContent = state;
        stateSelect.appendChild(stateOption);
    });
    stateInput.appendChild(stateSelect);
}

// Call the function to display state names
displayStateNames();

// Call the function to display state names
displayStateNames();

// Call the function to detect number of states and cities
const numberOfStatesAndCities = detectNumberOfStatesAndCities();
console.log(numberOfStatesAndCities);
// Get a reference to the HTML element where you want to display the state names
const container = document.getElementById('container');

// Iterate over the states array
states.forEach(state => {
    // Create a new paragraph element for each state
    const paragraph = document.createElement('p');

    // Set the text content of the paragraph to the state name
    paragraph.textContent = state;

    // Append the paragraph to the container
    container.appendChild(paragraph);
});

 const stateInput = document.querySelector('.state-us');
    const stateSelect = document.createEement('select');

is HTML class which is state-us when i use in Blade of Laravel its Not Showing Which state is that
.state-us

